# Markup id set on a component that is usually not rendered into markup

Tags: java, wicket

I am getting this message:

> Markup id set on a component that is usually not rendered into markup. Markup id: pnlMessages3a, component id: pnlMessages, component tag: wicket:panel.

The panel is added to a enclosing panel like this:

`add(new MessagePanel("pnlMessages"));`

in html

`<wicket:panel wicket:id="pnlMessages">tblData</wicket:panel>`

Within the MessagePanel I am calling *super(id)* passing the component id "pnlMessages" to the parent class. There is no other component within the class MessagePanel that enables the OutputMarkupId.

So why do I get the warning?

I have to mention that some Labels and images are updated within the MessagePanel using *AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior*

Comment: I found out that the generated MessagePanel html contains an id
<wicket:panel wicket:id="pnlMessages" id="pnlMessages6">

So there is an additional id next to the wicket:id that I did not include in my source html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you misuse `<wicket:panel>`. 
Its purpose is to wrap the HTML content of MyPanel.html. I.e. Wicket will use the content `<wicket:panel> CONTENT </wicket:panel>` as markup that should be included into another panel or a page.

In addition any `<wicket:xyz>` element is not rendered by Wicket in production mode. So trying to update such HTML element with Ajax will fail because it won't be in the DOM.

You should replace it with: `<div wicket:id="pnlMessages">tblData</div>`

Comment: What do you mean with 'replace it with tblData' ? tblData is just a String-placeholder. At least thats what I thought. I removed it like this :
<wicket:panel wicket:id="pnlMessages" />
And it did not make any difference.

Comment: I used the wrong quote and SO didn't show it properly.